# Primes $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$ satisfying $(\cos(2\pi/7))^{1/3}+(\cos(4\pi/7))^{1/3}+(\cos(6\pi/7))^{1/3}=\left(\frac{a-b\sqrt[3]c}d\right)^{1/3}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, contest-math, roots-of-cubics

**Source**: [Enumeration 2022 Prelims](https://www.pravega.org/pdf/Enumeration_Prelims_2022_rectified.pdf) conducted by the Indian Institute of Science (question $10$ under objectives)

**Problem statement**:

> Primes $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$ satisfy the following equation. $$\left(\cos\frac{2\pi}{7}\right)^{\frac 13}+\left(\cos\frac{4\pi}{7}\right)^{\frac 13}+\left(\cos\frac{6\pi}{7}\right)^{\frac 13}=\left(\frac{a-b\times\sqrt[3]c}{d}\right)^{\frac 13}$$ Find the value of $a+b+c+d$.

**My attempt**:

Let $\alpha=\cos\frac{2\pi}7$, $\beta=\cos\frac{4\pi}7$, $\gamma=\cos\frac{6\pi}7$. It can be established that:

- $\alpha+\beta+\gamma=-\frac{1}{2}$
- $\alpha\beta+\beta\gamma+\gamma\alpha=-\frac{1}2$
- $\alpha\beta\gamma=\frac{1}{8}$

Thus, $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$ are roots of the cubic equation $8x^3+4x^2-4x-1=0$.

---

Is there any way to find the sum of cube roots of the roots of a cubic? I am not sure what to do next. How do I manage such questions in a short time in the setting of a contest? I am not sure if the latter part of my question is in the scope of this site.

I would appreciate alternate ways to approach this problem as well.

Comment: Yes. Thanks a lot. I couldn't find it despite my efforts. I am submitting  yes vote to close.

Comment: FYI, using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24(%5Ccos%5Cfrac%7B2%5Cpi%7D%7B7%7D)%5E%7B%5Cfrac%2013%7D%2B(%5Ccos%5Cfrac%7B4%5Cpi%7D%7B7%7D)%5E%7B%5Cfrac%2013%7D%2B(%5Ccos%5Cfrac%7B6%5Cpi%7D%7B7%7D)%5E%7B%5Cfrac%2013%7D%3D(%5Cfrac%7Ba-b%5Ctimes%5Csqrt%5B3%5Dc%7D%7Bd%7D)%5E%7B%5Cfrac%2013%7D%24&p=1), in addition to the duplicate here (using that $\cos\frac{8\pi}{7}=\cos\frac{6\pi}{7}$), there's also several AoPS threads, e.g., [Trigonometric Sum](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1598153p9931722), ...

Comment: (cont.) [Trigonometry with cube root](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1079891p4739088) (with its post #$4$ stating this is a famous identity found by Ramanujan), etc.

Comment: @JohnOmielan so this is how reputed users here manage to flag duplicates within seconds!